# Reuse style and attrib from sdk

Tags: android, android-styles

How to reuse style from Android SDK?
I am trying use part of `....\android-sdk\platforms\android-11\data\res\layout\number_picker.xml`

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/numberpicker_input"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/numberPickerInputTextStyle" />  <------- HERE ERROR
```

And I get an error in xml editor `error: Error: Attribute is not public. (at 'style' with value '?android:attr/numberPickerInputTextStyle').`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an attribute from the SDK that was declared private. You cannot use them in your project. One way to overcome this specific problem (numberpicker styling), you could consider using the following library:

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker

Comment: I need just create button with same style as number picker and use original number picker. And I thought that this is easy way.